# New Linux Mint 16 installation, wifi connects and then drops almost immediately

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, linux-mint

I don't really know how to get into much more detail than the title has provided. I'm on a new HP Pavilion 15 and running Linux Mint 16 x64, but the wifi keeps dropping almost immedi ately (<1 min) after connecting and then doesn't allow me to reconnect. I'm dual booting windows 7 and it has no issues whatsoever with the wifi. Please request any additional information and I will provide it as soon as possible.

**Edit for MariusMatutiae:**

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
```

Comment: Can you post the output of lspci -nn | grep -i net?

Comment: Updated, please take a look.

Comment: Also post the output of `dmesg | tail -n 20` just after the wifi disconnects please.

Comment: MariusMatutiae's solution seems to have worked, thanks though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The support for your wifi card, Ralink Rt3290, is still experimental, in Linux. You can see it [here](http://wikidevi.com/wiki/AzureWave_AW-NB087H). Still we can try this as follows: go to an empty directory, and issue these commands:

```
    sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential linux-firmware
  wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.12.2/backports-3.12.2-1.tar.bz2
   tar xvf backports-3.12.2-1.tar.bz2
   cd backports-3.12.2-1/
   make defconfig-wifi
   make
   sudo make install
```

Shutdown and reboot, hopefully it will work.